# T4 templates don't work for me in my Visual studio 2008 solution

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3, t4

I download the latest version of Subsonic(3.0.0.3) but when I add the T4 templates in my solution in Visual studio 2008 SP1, the auto-generation don't work. If I right click on the template files also the "Run custom tools" is not present.
What I have to do to make visual studio able to generate code from T4 templates?

Comment: Which edition of VS2008 are you using?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a SubSonic problem.  I suggest you add a "T4" tag to your post to get more people looking at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check what type of project you are using.

T4 Templates don't run in "Web Site" projects (as opposed to "Web application" projects). If you're using a web site project, you must add a Code project as well, put your templates in there and reference that project in your website.